# How can I append a relatively sized label to an image?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have a large number of images with different sizes, ranging from 16x16 to 512x512.

I want to append a black label to each of these images saying "Demo Version".

Since the images comes in widely different sizes, I want the label size to be relative to the image. I don't want to make the image wider.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a php version as that is what I use - also you do not say what platform etc. you are using. This will add a lable below the image as I think that is what you want - you can watermark instead if that is what you want with the second example.

[image]

```
exec("montage -geometry +0+0 -background skyblue -label \"Sunflower\" original.jpg output.jpg");
```

Watermark with an embossed type text

[image]

```
// Get the size of the image 
$size = getimagesize("$input14"); 

// Size for watermark - scaled to fit the image 
$width = $size[0]*.9; 
$height = $size[0]*.25; 

// Create an image with the text
$cmd = "-size {$width}x{$height} -background none -font Utopia-bold ". 
" -fill white -gravity center caption:\"Copyright of Rubblewebs\" ". 
" -shade 240x40"; 

exec("convert $cmd font.png "); 

// Add the text image to the photo 
exec("composite -watermark 30% -gravity south font.png $input14 embossed.png"); 

// Delete the tempory image 
unlink ('font.png');
```

Comment: No reply then @adamsilver ?